# Picking unique random numbers from a range

Tags: python, random

I am trying to pick 3 unique random numbers, all have to be different from 5. I am currently using the following code:

```
numbers = []
while len(numbers) < 3:
    num = random.choice([i for i in range(10) if i != 5])
    if num not in numbers:
        numbers.append(num)
```

Usually, this code works, but sometimes I get less than 3 numbers in the numbers list.
Can you help me find the problem with the code, or suggest a new code that works?

Comment: Why not `random.sample([i for i in range(10) if i != 5], 3)`? There's no way to exit that loop with fewer than three numbers in the list, so I don't think this is reproducible.

Comment: It is the first time I hear of this method. Will it pick different unique numbers every time?

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot!